# How do I change the format of an excel workbook from 'General' to 'Text'

Tags: python, excel

I am unable to change the whole workbook from General to Text I am only able to change individual cells

Any help would be much appreciated

Syntax I have that works for individual cell

Worksheet[].number_format = numbers.FORMAT_TEXT

Comment: Workbooks don't have a  number format. Neither do worksheets. Only cells have a number format.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

@BigBen is correct, only cells have a number format. By extension, a range (a bunch of cells) can also be given a format. Loop through each worksheet in the workbook and set all cells on that sheet to text. This example sets the Used Range rather than the entire sheet, but the process will be similar, you'll just have to specify the entire sheet. That's not difficult, I'm just keeping the example simple.

```
Sub Format()
    Dim wkshCurrent As Worksheet
    
    For Each wkshCurrent In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        wkshCurrent.UsedRange.NumberFormat = "@"
    Next wkshCurrent
End Sub
```